# Get attributes of hidden files

Tags: vba, attributes, hidden

I'm trying to get all [non-empty] file attributes from a specified directory. How to loop through the directory and set the files as unhidden [the "For Each ..." omits them]?

```
Sub SomeProc()

Dim sFile As Variant
Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oDir:   Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("c:\SomePath")

SetAttr "c:\SomePath\SomeFile.accdb", vbNormal

For Each sFile In oDir.Items
    For i = 0 To 288
        If oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i) <> "" Then
            Debug.Print i & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, i) & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i)
        End If
    Next i
Next

SetAttr "c:\SomePath\SomeFile.accdb", vbHidden

End Sub
```

edit:

Thanks to Alex K.'s hint [his code wasn't showing the values of the attributes] i managed to do this: it works but i guess there are performance issues [and it doesn't take into account subfolders - not a problem]

```
Sub SomeProc()

Const PATH As String = "c:\SomePath\"

Dim sFile As Variant
Dim sFileName As String
Dim oShell As Object
Dim oDir As Object
Dim i, k As Long

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(PATH)

sFileName = Dir$(PATH & "*.*", vbHidden)
k = 0
Do Until Len(sFileName) = 0
k = k + 1

Set sFile = oDir.parsename(sFileName)
For i = 0 To 288
    If oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i) <> "" Then
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, k).Value = i & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(oDir.Items, i) & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, i)
    End If
Next i

sFileName = Dir$()
Loop

End Sub
```

I have found also different approach: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vb_fileattributes.html

Answer (score 1):

`GetDetailsOf()` works for hidden files, its only the enumeration that does not.

Use the built-in `Dir$()` function to list files, telling it to include those with the Hidden attrib

```
Sub SomeProc()
Const PATH As String = "c:\SomePath\"

Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oDir As Object
Dim sFileName As String
Dim i As Long

Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(PATH)
sFileName = Dir$(PATH & "*.*", vbHidden)

Do Until Len(sFileName) = 0
    For i = 0 To 288
        If oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFileName, i) <> "" Then
            Debug.Print i & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFileName, i) & ": " & oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFileName, i)
        End If
    Next i

    sFileName = Dir$()
Loop
End Sub
```